# Select y Order BY en mysql no me esta funcionando bien

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla juego

```
id usuarios correctas incorrectas
1  pablo     5          0
2  pablo1    2          1
3  pablo2    10         5
4  pablo3    20         10
5  pablo4    4          0
```

Tengo el siguiente select mysql

```
SELECT * FROM juego ORDER BY correctas DESC LIMIT 10
```

El problema que tengo es que no me los ordena correctamente, ya que por ejemplo el 10 o 20 lo ordena como si es un 1 o 2 y la verdad no encuentro el problema. Si me pueden ayudar se los agradeceria. gracias.

Comment: Y el campo no será un varchar?

Comment: si, ahi debe estar el problema, lo cambio por INT verdad?.

Comment: Sí. Mientras sea de tipo string efectivamente el orden alfabético pone un 10 antes de un 3.

Comment: ok, ha sido muy amable.